# How do I register my component (with constructor parameters) so an exception isn't thrown when I try to resolve it?

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I have following situation:

```
public interface IFormater
    {
        StyleInformation GetStyleInformation(Fact fact);
        FactType[] Formats { get; }
    }

public const string STYLENAME = "ABZ Date Style";

        ILocalization localization;

        public DateFormater(ILocalization localization)
        {
            this.localization = localization;
        }

        public StyleInformation GetStyleInformation(Fact fact)
        {
            return new StyleInformation(STYLENAME, false, false, false, false, false, true, localization.DateFormat);
        }

        public FactType[] Formats
        {
            get { return new FactType[] { FactType.Date }; }
        }

public class FormattingFacade
    {
        List<IFormater> formatters;
        IWindsorContainer container;

        public FormattingFacade(IWindsorContainer container)
        {
            this.container = container;
            formatters = new List<IFormater>();
            var formaterInterface = typeof(IFormater);
            foreach (Type type in this.GetType().Assembly.GetTypes())
            {
                if (formaterInterface.IsAssignableFrom(type) && !type.Equals(formaterInterface))
                {
                    container.Register(Component.For(new Castle.Core.ComponentModel(type.FullName, type, type)));
                    formatters.Add((IFormater)container.Resolve(type));
                }
            }
        }

        public StyleInformation GetStyleInformation(Fact fact)
        {
            foreach (IFormater formater in formatters)
                if (formater.Formats.Contains(fact.Concept.XbrlBaseType)) return formater.GetStyleInformation(fact);
            throw new NoFormaterException();
        }
    }
```

The problem is that castle throws exception when tries to resolve formater that has some parameters in constructor. If there is formater with only no arg constructor it works.
How should I register and how should I resolve these types but to keep this level of flexibility.

Comment: Do you only want IFormatter's that have a parameter-less constructor? Or do you want the flexibility to register any type of IFormatter?

Comment: I want to register any type of IFormatter. Just to say, all dependencies of formaters are registered and can be resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it this way:

```
int i = 0;
foreach (Type type in this.GetType().Assembly.GetTypes())
{
        if (formaterInterface.IsAssignableFrom(type) && !type.Equals(formaterInterface))
        {
                container.Register(Component.For<IFormater().ImplementedBy(type).Named(i.ToString()));
                formatters.Add(container.Resolve<IFormater>(i.ToString()));
                i++;
        }
}
```

I just registered components with generic aproach and to be able to do that I named each one of them by number key. I tested this one. It's working well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want Windsor to be able to resolve the component, then Windsor needs to know how to resolve every parameter of the matching constructor.  You either need to make sure all of the dependencies are registered in Windsor and/or create a [sub-dependency resolver](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Resolvers.ashx) to handle the other cases (where the required parameters are not registered in Windsor).